# SQL Insert Performance

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I am using a `DataTable` and the `MySqlAdapater` to insert around 100 000 rows with around 40 columns to a MySQL database.

I chose this way, because my program needs run on mono (unix / mac) where I could not establish a connection to my database via the `System.Data.Sql` package, but only via the .NET connector Mysql.Data.MySqlClient which has no `SqlBulkCopy`-method.

Additionally the amount of columns in my table is flexible, so I was looking for an easy way to iterate the columns. Thats why I used the way:

- Parsing my data
- Loading it into a `DataTable` Object
- Create a MySQL table dynamically based on my `DataTable` Object
- Use a MySqlDataAdapter to bulk insert the DataTable to the Database via its `.Update()`-method

Right now, it takes around 3-4 minutes to insert 100 000 rows this way - which is subjectively slow (mac mini 2012, i7, 512 GB SSD, 16 GB ram)

Is there any way to speed this up with the `Mysql.Data.MySqlClient` ?

```
public static void Import(DataTable dt, string tableName, string conString)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
            {
                con.Open();

                string createTableString = GetCreateTableSql(dt, tableName);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(createTableString, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                using (MySqlCommand selectcmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + dt.TableName, con))
                {
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(sda);
                        sda.SelectCommand = selectcmd;

                        builder.GetUpdateCommand();

                        using (DataTable dttemp = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dttemp);
                            // prevent duplicating data
                            if (dttemp.Rows.Count == 0)
                            {
                                dttemp.Merge(dt);
                                sda.Update(dttemp);
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Data already present. Delete manually");
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on the table? If so try dropping them and recreating after the insert.

Comment: Have you tried setting `UpdateBatchSize` on the `MySqlDataAdapter` to something like 500 or 1000?

Comment: I don't follow why you are loading dttemp.Merge(dt); from dt.TableName , then merging, and then update.

Comment: My experience w/ `Merge` is that it is sloooow. We threw away one that took 8+ hours. As a stored procedure it now runs in seconds. This was the absolute worst culprit, but in general C# pretending to be a RDBMS is a poor performer.  An RDBMS engine is optimal for doing relational set operations. Use it. The "oh look, Mo! Working disconnected!" Microsoft propaganda is a [pig in a poke.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_in_a_poke)  P.S. Ours is an Oracle DB.

Comment: @eurotrash I can not use `sda.Update()` without indexes. @RobH thanks for the hint, but I tried (1000) and it took twice as much time as before

Answer (score 3):

Some quick remarks:

- Naming is important. I don't consider `dt`, `conString`, `con`, etc. proper names since they don't tell me enough. There's no need to abbreviate. `selectcmd` doesn't follow Microsoft's rules about compound words, and `dttemp` even contains the dreaded "temp".
- You haven't encapsulated the `MySqlCommand` which creates the table in a `using`.
- `MySqlCommandBuilder` inherits from a class that implements `IDisposable`, so perhaps that too should be used in a `using` statement?

Comment: thanks for the hints! I will take more care about this. Do you have a hint for the performance issues as well?